# Warning in foreach loop?

Tags: php

Why am I getting the following warning:

> [Fri Mar 25 19:19:21 2011] [error]
>   [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning: 
>   Invalid argument supplied for
>   foreach() in /var/www/register.php on
>   line 60, referer:
>   http://localhost/register.php

when running the following script:

```
<?php
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.ico">

        <?php
            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ) {
                $err = array();

                if( empty( $_POST['display_name'] ) ) $err[] = "display name field is required";
                if( empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) $err[] = "email field is required";
                if( empty( $_POST['password'] ) ) $err[] = "password field is required";

                if( !$err ) {
                    try {
                        $DBH = new PDO( "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database1", "user", "pass" );
                        $DBH -> setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );

                        $STH = $DBH -> prepare( "insert into table1 (display_name, email, password) values ( :display_name, :email, :password )" );

                        $STH -> bindParam( ':display_name', $_POST['display_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 100 );
                        $STH -> bindParam( ':email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 100 );
                        $STH -> bindParam( ':password', $_POST['password'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 100 );

                        $STH -> execute();

                        $STH = $DBH -> prepare( "insert into table2 ( username, status, users_id ) values ( :username, :status, :users_id )" );

                        $strStatus = 1;

                        $STH -> bindParam( ':username', $_POST['display_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 100 );
                        $STH -> bindParam( ':status', $strStatus, PDO::PARAM_INT, 1 );
                        $STH -> bindParam( ':users_id', $_POST['referer'], PDO::PARAM_INT, 1 );

                        $STH -> execute();

                        $DBH = null;
                    } catch( PDOException $e ) {
                        echo $e -> getMessage();
                    }

                    header( "Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );
                    exit;
                } else {
                    foreach( $_POST as $key => $val ) {
                        $form[$key] = htmlspecialchars($val);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $form['display_name'] = $form['email'] = $form['password'] = '';
            }
        ?>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php foreach( $err as $line ) { ?>
        <div style="error"><?php echo $line; ?></div>
        <?php } ?>

        <h1>register</h1>

        <form method="post">
            referers id:<br />
            <input type="text" name="referer" /><br /><br />

            name:<br />
            <input type="text" name="display_name" value="<?php echo $form['display_name']; ?>" /><br /><br />

            email:<br />
            <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $form['email']; ?>" /><br /><br />

            password:<br />
            <input type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo $form['password']; ?>" /><br /><br />

            <input type="submit" value="register" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are trying to access a variable that, under certain conditions, doesn't exist. If your page's form wasn't submitted, the `$err` variable wouldn't exist.

You can fix this by placing `$err = array();` outside your `if` statement. Change:

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ) {
   $err = array();
```

To:

```
$err = array();
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

That error occurs when the argument is not an array. You should put `if(is_array($_POST))` before/around your `foreach` to make sure it's not supplied with a null value.

Answer (score 0):

I think your session isn't always initialized so you get an invalid argument because it doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of warning you get when you try to iterate over something that is not an array.

Before the following line :

```
foreach( $err as $line ) {
```

Make sure that `$err` is indeed an array.

Two solutions :

- **initialize `$err`** earlier, outside of the condition that tests if `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'`, so it at least contains an empty array
- Or don't try to iterate over `$err` if it's not set -- using [**`isset()`**](https://www.php.net/isset) to test for that